# Truncated strings with TextBoxFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In our ASP.Net MVC 3 application we're getting truncated strings on our forms when the string value contains a double-quote.

For example, given a textbox:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.County)
```

If the user enters the string: 'Hampshire"County', when rendering the value back out to the form, only the string 'Hampsire' is displayed. If I inspect the value in the model, the double-quote is escaped as 'Hampshire\"County'. In Fiddler, the posted value is correct and the value is stored in the database correctly, so it would appear to be related to the Html helper that renders the textbox out to the client.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Why is there  `"` in the middle of your data anyway? That input should be validated, and perhaps removed? Otherwise you will end up with PITA scenarios like the one you're experiencing now :)

Comment: Does the final HTML rendered by the view look correct (apart from having the wrong value in the text box)? Can you post it?

Comment: Are you sure it's a double quote and not two apostrophes side by side?

Comment: @AndreiV how two apostrophes side by side could be escaped as '\"'?

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, unfortunately Jason, yes, as much as they're a PITA, we need to allow double quotes. Business requirement and all that. As it turns out, it was something we were doing that caused the issue, I'll explain in an answer to my own question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out this was a problem of our own making. It turns out some bright spark (me) about 9 months ago thought it would be a good idea to override the HtmlAttributeEncode() method in a custom HttpEncoder. This fires during output rendering.

The reason I added this was that parts of the application need to render script blocks to the client, and the default encoder was screwing with the JS code in the HTML.

When we removed the overriding method, the problem went away. Lesson learned: don't screw around with the framework unless you absolutely need to.

Once again, thanks all for taking the time to consider this.

Answer (score 0):

I was unabled to reproduce this issue. Just created a new MVC 3 project, created a controller with 2 actions (GET and POST), with a typed view, receiving an object with a string property `Text`, and displaying it inside a form... It all proceeds as expected. No issues. Everything I type in, is posted, and comes back correctly in the POST.

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.MyClass
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Home</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Text)
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyClass data)
    {
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

So, the problem must be somewhere else... with something that can mess with the value being rendered (editor templates, javascript)

Try looking at the source of the rendered page to see if the value there is correct, if it is, then it must be javascript, otherwise, it must be something in the server.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this Miguel, turns out it was a problem of our own making, I'll answer my own question to explain what we had done wrong.